# cURL POST Error 411 even when Content-Length specified

Tags: curl, post, command-line

I cannot get what should be a simple POST to work. It's been very straightforward in Postman, but translating to command line cURL is not my strength (I do NOT use PHP).

This is the line I've been trying (and variations of it):

***cURL --request POST --url https://r1-api.dotmailer.com/v2/segments/refresh/155195 --user "user:password" -H 'Content-Length: 0'***

This pulls back the following error:

> HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length

Any ideas? I'm new to the REST API. I've managed to find my way around most issues but this has been a sticking point.

Here's the Postman cURL rendering:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify empty data and remove Content-Length header.

curl will set "Content-Length: 0" itself.

This should work for you:

```
curl --data '' --request POST --url https://r1-api.dotmailer.com/v2/segments/refresh/155195 --user "user:password"
```

Comment: A belated thank you for this. It didn't quite work but got me that step closer so I figured it out:
curl --data '' --request POST --url https://r1-api.dotmailer.com/v2/segments/refresh/155195 --user "user:password" -H "Content-Type: application/json"